# Testing jquery click call back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

Am a newbie in `jasmine`, trying to test the jquery `click` call back function

```
$('#upload-btn').click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

My test code is

```
describe('upload button attaches to modal', function(){
    it('attaches successfully', inject(function($controller, $httpBackend) {
        spyOn($.fn, "click");
        spyOn($.fn, "modal");
        $httpBackend.expectGET('service/search/populate/procedureNumberList');
        var scope = {}, ctrl = $controller('uploadARController', {
            $scope : scope
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($('#upload-btn').click).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
        $('#upload-btn').click();
        expect($.fn.modal).toHaveBeenCalled() <<<---- Failing here;
    }));
})
```

But am getting the below when I execute the test

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) Upload AR Test upload button attaches to modal attaches successfully FAILED
        Expected spy modal to have been called.
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.165 secs / 0.026 secs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to make it work.
First i started to use [jasmine-jquery](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/velesin/jasmine-jquery/jasmine-jquery-1.3.1.js) library to load the `html` using `setFixtures` because for the `jquery click` to work it needs to first get an instance of the `jquery selector`.

Then i `spyOn` on the `modal` using

```
spyOn($.fn, "modal");
```

The difference being all `spying` should happen only on `beforeEach` for some reason, if inside the real test its not working (not sure why).

Then using `jquery`, `click` on the button.

```
$('#upload-btn').click();
```

Then finally `expect` on the `spied modal`.

```
expect($("#myModal").modal).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Finally

```
beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {
 setFixtures('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="upload-btn" >Upload</button>');
 spyOn($.fn, 'modal');
}));
```

The Test:

```
describe('upload button attaches to modal', function(){
  it('attaches successfully', function() {
    inject(function($controller){
     var scope = {}, ctr = $controller('uploadARController', {$scope:scope});
    });
    $('#upload-btn').click();
    expect($("#myModal").modal).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
})
```